# Parameters of Poreitz Gader

Tags: halacha, minhag

What are the parameters for the curse of "Haporeitz Gader Yenashcho Nachash - One who breaks a fence should be bitten by a snake"? (Koheles, [Avodah Zara 27b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.27b.7-9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

What kind of halachos does this apply to?
Does it apply if the action is done in private?

Answer (score 1):

See Avoda Zara 27b and Shabbat 110a.

This statement is a curse against people who  doesn't follow a kind of rabbinical prohibition s called gedarim.

The Gader is a security fence made by Sages. As the **Mishna in Avot (1.1)** explains seyag latora. The purpose of the fence is to avoid contact with the isur Tora (¹). The Mesilat Yesharim explains that this principle is  demonstrated in one of the mitzvot of the Tora, Nazir. He cannot eat grapes, or vine leaves because of they are related with wine. The Tora gives an example of gader to help Sages how to make fences, or at least an example of personal fences, that are an other topic.

Porets gader is one who isn't afraid about isur Tora and he thinks he can avoid alone isure Tora. And he doesn't follow Sages. E.g. Gemara in AZ 27b states that Minut (a seductive theory of kfira, dangerous for Jews) is so dangerous that it's prohibited to get help by a doctor who is Min, or treat with Minut. If one treats himself with such a doctor, a "Snake Derabanan" will bite him. Its bite is treatment resistent. Note that some rishonim understand that the curse is extended to all mitzvot derabanan as blessings derabanan for food or other berachot derabanan (²). source describing this curse is the verse in Kohelet quoted by the OP.

---

(¹): Rambam comment Avot 1, 1.

> ..ועשו סייג לתורה. ר"ל הגזירות והתקנות אשר ירחיקו האדם מן העבירות כמו שאמר יתברך ושמרתם משמרתי ונאמר בפירושו עשו משמרת למשמרתי: ‏
>
> Seyag (fence). Decrets of sages that keep away people from sins as says g-d in the verse, "to keep my guard" and sages interpreted you need to make a fence around my fence. (loose translation).

Rabenu Yona there.

> א׳:א׳
>   ועשו סייג לתורה. כענין שנאמר (ויקרא י"ח ל') ושמרתם את משמרתי כלומר עשו משמרת למשמרתי. והסייג הוא דבר גדול ומשובח לעשות סייג וגדר למצות לבל יוכל להכשל בהם הירא את דבר ה'. לכן המקיים את דברי חז"ל שהם סייגים למצות של תורה חיבב היראה ממי שעושה המצוה עצמה כי אין עשיית המצות הוכחה ליראה כמו השומר לסייגים שהוא נזהר מתחלה שלא יביא לידי פשיעה. **אך העושה המצוה ואינו מקיים הסייג מראה לנו כי אם ייטיב בעיניו לעשות מצוה אל ירע בעיניו אם יפשע בה ולפרוץ פרץ לא חש מפני היראה ופורץ גדר ישכנו נחש**.‏
>
> Who makes mitzvah and not the fence show that he is not afraid to fall and does sin, breaking is not a preoccupation for him, One who breaks a fence should be bitten by a snake
>   For instance the term is used in masechet Nidda several times. See Rashi Nidda 3.2
>
> סייג. חזוק וגדר מדרבנן לטמא למפרע
>
> (For a woman who find blood when checking herself, to view herself unclean retroactively ...) Enhancement and fence made by Rabbis.

(²). Sefer Hachinuch 430

> ...ומי שעבר ולא בירך כל שאר הברכות שבעולם לבד אלו שזכרנו ביטל מצות חכמים לבד, ופורץ גדר ישכנו נחש והזהיר בהן יתברך מדה כנגד מדה.‏